# How to use iAd to show and hide ads

Tags: ios, iad

I want to use iADs in my application. how can I show ads in free one and hide them in paid one mean show full view application. here is code that is using some space for ads

```
adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
CGRect bannerFrame = self.adBannerView.frame;
bannerFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;
self.adBannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
```

Comment: Are your free and paid applications separate applications, or is the full version unlocked via in app purchase?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this purpose.
For purchased application add a value to the NSUserDefaults like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"Purchased"];
```

Before showing the iAd check the value like:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Purchased"])
{
   //Dont display iAd
}
else
{
   //display the iAd
}
```